# How to stop AngularFire2 function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using AngularFire2 Authentication. All is working fine. Now what I wanted to achieve is, check it user is already in the userlist, then just update lastLogin the next time the facebook login button is clicked.

Else create a new user.

This works fine. But I can't get to stop the updateLogin() / _addUser() function to stop after updating the database.

It just keeps going. (89...)auth.service.ts:98 successfully logged in!

Here is the updateLogin()

```
private _updateLogIn(thisurl, data) {
    return thisurl.update({ 
        lastLogIn: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        avatar: data.photoURL
      }).then((success) => {
        console.log("successfully logged in!");
      }); ;
  }
```

I call this with the authentication() function as follow:

```
login(provider: string) {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: this._getProvider(provider)
    }).then(
        (success) => {
       this.authenticate(success);
   })
   return;
  }

    authenticate(user: any): any {
         if(!user) {
          return {};
        } else {
        let data = user.auth.providerData[0];
        this.api_url = this.af.database.object(`${this.path}/${user.auth.uid}`);
         this._isUsers().subscribe(value => {
           var filtered =  value.filter(function(item) {
                return item.uid === user.auth.uid;
            });
            if(filtered.length > 0){this._updateLogIn(this.api_url, data); return; }
            else{ this._addUser(this.api_url, user, data); return;
               }
          });
         return;
        }
      }

 _isUsers(){
   return this.usersList.map(snapshot => {
         return snapshot;
     });
  }

private _addUser(thisurl, user, data){
    return thisurl.set({
          name: data.displayName,
          username: data.displayName.replace(/ /g,"."),
          avatar: data.photoURL,
          email: data.email,
          provider: data.providerId,
          uid: user.auth.uid,
          lastLogIn: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
      }).then((success) => {
        console.log("successfully signed up!");
        return;
      }); 
 }
```

How I stop the function execution to just once?
This basically hacks my browser tab.

(89...)auth.service.ts:98 successfully logged in!

Comment: You should include the implementations of `_isUsers` and `_addUser`, too.

Comment: You don't seem to have `createUser` in there either. Please try to include a [mcve] in your questions or at least include all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most like related to the observable returned by `_isUsers()`. Although it's not clear from the question's code, it seems likely that the `this.usersList` returned by that function is an AngularFire2 `list` of all users.

AngularFire2 `list` and `object` observables emit data whenever the database changes, so it's likely that your setting the user data in `_updateLogIn` results in another list of users being emitted, etc.

To solve the problem, you could use the `first` operator:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

this._isUsers().first().subscribe(...)
```

However, it's not clear why you need to subscribe to that observable in the first place. You might want to consider refactoring the code in your question, as it seems overly complicated.

It's generally a good idea to avoid as many `subscribe` calls as possible. You might want to read [*RxJS: Don’t Unsubscribe*](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87#.tuifoxaz1).